# Select the second tab in a section of a page

Tags: javascript, tabs

index.html#section navigates you to a certain section of a page. But I want to **select the second tab in a section of a page**. I don't know if it can be done without javascript but using [Tab Content Script (v 2.2)](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/tabcontent.htm) with the method *instance.expandit(tabid_or_position)* would seem to work. However, I'm having a hard time figuring out how to **select the second tab in a section of a page**.

Hope you could help me with this. Thanks!

Comment: do you want to make second tab as a default selected tab when the page loads?

Comment: @vertexion nope. i have a button somewhere in the page and i wanted to navigate on the second tab of the section once it is clicked. is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, you want to navigate to the tab when a button is clicked. 
Though not a clean way, but you may simulate a `click` action on tab once the is button clicked.

```
var element = document.getElementById('coupon-navigator');
element.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    document.getElementById('tab2').click();
}, false);
```

Comment: i can't make it work. i put the code before the </body> tag. is that right? btw, i'm working in wordpress wherein the footer is separated. will that function well?

this is what i put in the footer.php before the end of body tag
`<script type="text/javascript">
    var element = document.querySelector('#coupon-navigator');
    element.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        document.querySelector('#tab2').click();
    }, false);
    </script>`

Comment: I have updated the code to match the `id`s of your elements, try it once! and yeah the closing of body tag is a good place to add this code.